# How to turn off spindle of internal HDD on MacBook from command line?

Tags: hardware, ssd

I'm going put SSD drive instead of DVD and move OS-X to SSD.
Big capacity HDD I'm gonig leave to have some place for large multimedia data and archives.

So I whant keep HHD in spindle off mode most time and mount it just on demand, what should I do to prevent HDD to be mounted and powered while system boot (after restart) and how to manage spindle with the command line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

to disable the drive from mounting during boot :

Find the uuid of the drive (in terminal):

```
diskutil info /Volumes/[name]
```

Then create a new file called /etc/fstab and in it put

```
UUID=34DFD44D-489C-1C22-01D8-DFDF288C102F none hfs rw,noauto 0 0
```

just replace the UUID above with the actual UUID of the drive.

Use the following command to view a list of drives/partitions

```
diskutil list
```

And then issue the mount command to mount the drive

```
sudo mount /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/DriveName
```

Obviously change the disk id and mount folder to suit your system.

Comment: Better use `diskutil mount [name]` and `diskutil umount [name]`.

Comment: Why it is better?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo diskutil eject /dev/disk1` will turn off spindle